# Comparing the elements in two JSON dicts and getting the difference as a ratio or percentage

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object and I am working on some data manipulation. I want to get the difference as a ratio  so I can more accurately rank the elements in my dict.

```
[{condition: functional, location:Sydney }, {condition:functional, location: Adelaide}, {condition:broken, location:Sydney}]
```

I can get the number of points where the location is not functional like so:

```
filter(lambda x: x['condition']!='functional', json_obj)
```

But I would like to return this as a percentage ratio.

Comment: What do you mean by broken? please elaborate..

Comment: @SIslam It means it is not functional or it is not working.

Comment: @ petergt Then the answer is given i think.

Comment: I need my result to be like so: `{Sydney: 50%, Adelaide:0%, ..., }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Counter` and `defaultdict` as below-

```
from collections import Counter,defaultdict

d = [{'condition': 'functional', 'location':'Sydney' }, {'condition':'functional', 'location': 'Adelaide'}, {'condition':'broken', 'location':'Sydney'}]

cities = [j['location'] for j in d]

#initialize data
data = defaultdict(float)
for city in cities:
    data[city]=0
#Count occurrances of a single city as a counter dictionary
counters = Counter((i['location'] for i in d))

#Do the calculation
for i in d:
    if i['condition']== 'functional':
        inc = (counters[i['location']]*100)/len(d)
        data[i['location']]+= float(inc)
    elif i['condition']== 'broken':
        dec = (counters[i['location']]*100)/len(d)
        data[i['location']]-=float(dec)
    else:
        raise Exception("Error")


print {k:"{0}%".format(v) for k,v in data.items()}
```

Output-

```
{'Sydney': '0.0%', 'Adelaide': '33.0%'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
a = [{'condition': 'functional', 'location':'Sydney' }, {'condition':'functional', 'location': 'Adelaide'}, {'condition':'broken', 'location':'Sydney'}]

b = filter(lambda x: x['condition']!='functional', a)

all_locations = [item['location'] for item in b]

result = {}

for location in all_locations:
    if location not in result.keys():
        result[location] = all_locations.count(location)*100/float(len(all_locations))

print result
```

It's will return percent for every location

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? This compares the elements in two JSON dicts and getting the difference as a ratio, as you ask for in the title. But reading the question body, it not really clear what it is you want to do.

This assumes that both dictionaries have the same keys.

```
def dictionary_similarity(d1, d2):
    return sum(d1[key] == d2[key] for key in d1) / float(len(d1))

dictionary_similarity(
    {'condition': 'functional', 'location': 'Sydney' }, 
    {'condition': 'functional', 'location': 'Adelaide'},)

0.5
```